# Regular Expression that matches a word, or nothing

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I'm really struggling to put a label on this, which is probably why I was unable to find what I need through a search.

I'm looking to match the following:

- Auto Reply
- Automatic Reply
- AutomaticReply

The platform that I'm using doesn't allow for the specification of case-insensitive searches. I tried the following regular expression:

```
.*[aA]uto(?:matic)[ ]*[rR]eply.*
```

Thinking that `(?:matic)` would cause my expression to match `Auto` or `Automatic`. However, it is only matching `Automatic`.

- What am I doing wrong?
- What is the proper terminology here?

This is using Perl for the regular expression engine (I think that's `PCRE` but I'm not sure).

Comment: If this is a Perl regex, you do not need `.*` at start and end, as the default is that a regex can match any part of a string and does not need to match all of it. You can add modifiers to the regex with the `(?^i: ... )` extended pattern.

Comment: @TLP I'll try that out. All I have is an input field on a web form in OTRS that allows me to specify a regular expression. I haven't dug into the source code to see what it does with the input, but it's likely what you say will work fine. Thanks.

Comment: `perl` != `PCRE`, [Check the difference](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/pcrecompat.3.html). Also, how does your platform not allow case-insensitive ? Have you tried setting the `i` modifier in your regex like `(?i)auto(?:matic)?\s*reply` ?

Comment: FYI, PCRE and the Perl regex engine are different, but mostly compatible regex systems.  Modern Perl even supports pluggable regex engines.  See http://www.pcre.org and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm using OTRS, which provides a webform from which to submit the regular expressions. I'm not sure what it does with it after there. I do know that OTRS is written in Perl. I've found zero documentation on what type of Regular Expression engine is in use, or what it does with the value after it's been entered.

Comment: It looks like my confusion about modifiers was perhaps because I was using incorrect modifiers! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`(?:...)` is to regex patterns as `(...)` is to arithmetic: It simply overrides precedence.

```
 ab|cd        # Matches ab or cd
 a(?:b|c)d    # Matches abd or acd
```

A `?` quantifier is what makes matching optional.

```
 a?           # Matches a or an empty string
 abc?d        # Matches abcd or abd
 a(?:bc)?d    # Matches abcd or ad
```

You want

```
(?:matic)?
```

Without the needless leading and trailing `.*`, we get the following:

```
/[aA]uto(?:matic)?[ ]*[rR]eply/
```

---

As @adamdc78 points out, that matches `AutoReply`. This can be avoided as using the following:

```
/[aA]uto(?:matic[ ]*|[ ]+)[rR]eply/
```

or

```
/[aA]uto(?:matic|[ ])[ ]*[rR]eply/
```

Comment: Is the `?:` necessary? Could I just do `(matic)?` instead?

Comment: @crush You could, but the then `matic` would be held in a capturing group; unless you actually need the value of `matic` the capturing group doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks for clarification. That is what I thought, but wasn't sure. Is there a technical name for the `?` after a capturing group?

Comment: @crush It is a quantifier.

Comment: `(matic)?` needlessly captures. You could do that, but it would be wasteful. Changed "modifier" to "quantifier" in my answer.

Comment: Very very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
/.*[aA]uto(?:matic)? *[rR]eply/
```

you were simply missing the `?` after `(?:matic)`

Answer (score 4):

```
[Aa]uto(?:matic ?| )[Rr]eply
```

This assumes that you do not want `AutoReply` to be a valid hit.

You're just missing the [optional ("?")](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) in the regex.  If you're looking to match the entire line after the reply, then including the `.*` at the end is fine, but your question didn't specify what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex with line start/end anchors:

```
^[aA]uto(?:matic)? *[rR]eply$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[aA] match a single character present in the list below
aA a single character in the list aA literally (case sensitive)
uto matches the characters uto literally (case sensitive)
(?:matic)? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed 
[greedy]
matic matches the characters matic literally (case sensitive)
 * matches the character   literally
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back 
as needed [greedy]
[rR] match a single character present in the list below
rR a single character in the list rR literally (case sensitive)
eply matches the characters eply literally (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different. Same result.

```
m/([aA]uto(matic)? ?[rR]eply)/
```

Tested Against:

```
Some other stuff....
    Auto Reply
    Automatic Reply
    AutomaticReply

Now some similar stuff that shouldn't match (auto).
```